# Regex Javascript: check for palindromes

Tags: javascript

I'm attempting to find a solution to check for a palindrome. When I use the code:

```js
function palindrome(str) {
  var checkSpecial = str.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9]/g, '');
  var checkPalindrome = str.split('').reverse().join('');
  return checkSpecial == checkPalindrome;
}
console.log(palindrome("_eye")); // false
```

It returns false. I can't seem to get non-alphanumeric characters to remove.

Comment: Neither comment makes sense, the result of replace is bring assigned to the string being checked, and the question is not adding to solve it only using a regular expression. The above code should work...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, of course `"eye" !== "eye_"`. You probably want

```js
function palindrome(str) {
  var checkSpecial = str.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9]/g, '');
  var checkPalindrome = checkSpecial.split('').reverse().join('');
  return checkSpecial == checkPalindrome;
}
console.log(palindrome("_eye")); // true
```

Comment: I understand where I went wrong. Thank you for your help with that. I'm new  to posting on Stack Overflow and I think its pretty cool how quickly others can identify the problem and correct it so quickly.

Comment: Good to hear. Don't forget to accept the answer!

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the special characters from both strings. Note that you are not trying to use regex to test for palindromes (which is good because that's impossible). Fixed version:

```js
function palindrome(str) {
  var checkSpecial = str.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9]/g, '');
  var checkPalindrome = checkSpecial.split('').reverse().join('');
  return checkSpecial == checkPalindrome;
}
console.log(palindrome("_eye")); // false
```

Comment: Thank you for your input. I understand where I went wrong with this.